# Hi, in following circuit how do i calculate value of inductors L1, L2, L3, L4. (Design equations for inductors)

Tags: design, inductor

[image]

What will be the design equation to calculate values of inductors L1, L2, L3, L4.

Comment: What are they being used to do?

Comment: Do you know how much filtering you need?  (eg.: How sensitive is the A/D system).  Does the datasheet or App Note list these as inductors or ferrite parts?  To reduce high frequency noise some fast MCU's use small smt ferrite parts at similar locations.

Answer (score 2):

BLM likely refers to Murata BLM series of chip ferrites.  See www.murata.com .  You might just select the ferrite part to reduce noise at the frequency that you believe would disrupt your circuit.  Just be sure that the DC resistance is not so high that it could give a significant voltage drop.

The Murata spec sheet should list these parts by recommended current, so if you know the current draw on the pins this will help with selection.